# Is there a size limit for putParcelableArrayListExtra?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-intent

I'm using putParcelableArrayListExtra to send an ArrayList which contains all songs on the device to another Activity.

Now i was wondering if there is any **size limit** for sending data through intents with `putParcelableArrayListExtra`.

Ex. What if someone has more than 10k songs on his device, would this cause any problems when sending an arraylist which contains alot of songs to another Activity?

**My code**

```
@Override
   public void onClickItem(int position) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            myList = Main.getInstance().songs;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListSongsActivity.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myList ", myList);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the size limit for the bundle while performing the Activity transaction. In case the limit is exceeded the **TransactionTooLargeException** is thrown.

```
The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb,
which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.
Consequently, this exception can be thrown when there are many
transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
are of moderate size.
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException

Comment: What does the 1Mb mean? 1Mb of data stored inside the Arraylist?

Comment: The 1Mb refers to the data put inside the bundle present with the Intent. And as in your case you are just sending the ArrayList with the Intent, then Yes the 1Mb refers to data stored inside the ArrayList.

Comment: And how can i determine what the size is of my arraylists? On my device i have around 350 songs which works fine but what if i have over 10000 songs or more? Should i look for other options to pass large arraylists to another activity?

Comment: It is not recommended to pass this much huge data through the bundle. Instead, you should use either **DB** or **LruCache** to store that data and then send the id you get after storing this data to the next Activity.

Comment: Yeah i tried with 10k songs on my device and logcat says this: E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1195060)

Comment: Then if you want the data just for the activity transaction, then you might want to use `LruCache`. If you want to store the data for longer, then you should use persistent storage like **File** or **DB**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208353/discussion-between-ashok-chaudhari-and-vince-vd).

Comment: What about using a singleton class? and just store with set and get?